# How to deploy service with using opentelemetry sending data to azure monitor(app insight)?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, open-telemetry, appinsights, azure-monitor

I have a simple react nodejs app(http://23.100.37.60:3080/) hosted in AKS, below is my nodejs backend server file, my deployment manifest yml file and my docker file. I followed this instruction(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=nodejs) trying to send data through opentelemetry to app insight, but never saw any data flow into app insight. I wonder if I have anything configured incorrectly. I would appreciate your help!

Server.js

```
const { HttpInstrumentation } = require('@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http');
const { AzureMonitorTraceExporter } = require("@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter");
const { BatchSpanProcessor, SimpleSpanProcessor, ConsoleSpanExporter } = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base");
const { NodeTracerProvider, NodeTracerConfig } = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node");
const { MeterProvider, MeterProviderOptions } = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics");
const { trace, context, diag, DiagConsoleLogger, DiagLogLevel } = require('@opentelemetry/api');
const { Resource } = require("@opentelemetry/resources");
const { SemanticResourceAttributes } = require("@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions");
const { registerInstrumentations } = require('@opentelemetry/instrumentation');

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express(),
bodyParser = require("body-parser");
port = 3080;

// place holder for the data
const users = [];

const testResource = new Resource({
  [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: "my-helloworld-service",
  [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAMESPACE]: "my-namespace",
  [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID]: "my-instance",
});

const tracerProviderConfig = {
  resource: testResource
};
const meterProviderConfig = {
  resource: testResource
};

const provider = new NodeTracerProvider(tracerProviderConfig);
diag.setLogger(new DiagConsoleLogger(), DiagLogLevel.ALL);

const meterProvider = new MeterProvider(meterProviderConfig);

// Create an exporter instance.
const exporter = new AzureMonitorTraceExporter({
  connectionString: "my connection string copied from app insight"
});

// Add the exporter to the provider.
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter));

provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));

provider.register();

registerInstrumentations({
  instrumentations: [new HttpInstrumentation()],
});

const tracer = trace.getTracer("example-basic-tracer-node-server");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../my-app/build')));

app.get('/api/users', (req, res) => {
  console.log('api/users called!')
  res.json(users);
});

app.post('/api/user', (req, res) => {
  const span = tracer.startSpan("add-user-span");
  const user = req.body.user;
  console.log('Adding user:::::', user);
  users.push(user);
  span.addEvent('a user has been added', {
      'user': JSON.stringify(user)
  })
  span.end();
  res.json("user addedd");
});

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../my-app/build/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on the port::${port}`);
});
```

manifest.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: react-webapp
  name: react-webapp
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: react-webapp
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: react-webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: danpoc0acr.azurecr.io/dan-poc0-app-sample:v2
        name: webapp
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources: {}
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3080 
status: {}

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: react-webapp
  labels:
    run: react-webapp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: react-webapp
  type: LoadBalancer
```

docker file

```
FROM node:10 AS ui-build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY my-app/ ./my-app/
RUN cd my-app && npm install && npm run build

FROM node:10 AS server-build
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=ui-build /usr/src/app/my-app/build ./my-app/build
COPY api/package*.json ./api/
RUN cd api && npm install
COPY api/server.js ./api/

EXPOSE 3080

CMD ["node", "./api/server.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The docker file in your question uses image node:10 which is not supported version for *both* :-

- Application Insights, *and*
- OpenTelemetry

Check the prerequisite section of the following docs for details - [Enable Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry for .NET, Node.js, and Python applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=nodejs-javascript#prerequisites)

You could try using the newer node images (v14, 16 or 18) which is supported by both - AppInsights as well as OpenTelemetry.

Also, note the **[limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=nodejs-javascript#limitations-of-the-preview-release)** for this preview release. Since "Live metrics" are not supported, the data ingestion by AppInsights might be delayed by a couple of minutes. Wait for ~5 minutes for the data to appear in AppInsights. You could check using the `union *` query in the applicationInsights logs to see if *any* data has arrived in AppInsights workspace after a couple of minutes.